# AttributeError: load (scapy packet.py)

Tags: python

I've looked around and could not find anything regarding this.  The issue is probably due to me being somewhat new to Python and I was hoping I could get some help here.

I came across this blog post from 2009: http://stacksmash.org/2009/09/packet-visualization-with-python/

However when I run this, I get the following error in line 1129 of Scapy's packet.py

```
$ python test-image.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test-image.py", line 9, in <module>
    if(len(pkt.load) > imgWidth):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 
    192, in __getattr__
  fld,v = self.getfield_and_val(attr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 
  189, in getfield_and_val
  return self.payload.getfield_and_val(attr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 
  189, in getfield_and_val
  return self.payload.getfield_and_val(attr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 
  1125, in getfield_and_val
  raise AttributeError(attr)
AttributeError: load
```

Is this maybe an issue with newer library versions (considering this is a blogpost from 2009) or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me with `Python 3.6.4`:

```
from PIL import Image
from scapy.all import rdpcap

capture = rdpcap('./capture.pcap')
imgHeight = len(capture)

imgWidth = max(len(packet) for packet in capture)

imgSize = imgWidth, imgHeight
print('Image Size: ', imgSize)

img = Image.new('RGB', imgSize, (255, 255, 255))

for i in range(0, imgHeight):
    for j in range(0, len(capture[i])):
        color = ord(str(capture[i])[j])
        # print('Writing pixel', (j,i), 'with value:', color)
        img.im.putpixel((j,i), (0, color, 0))

img.save('./result.png')
```

Comment: Ah interesting.  Yeah I'm using Python 2.7 here so I guess that may be it.  I'm going to mark this as the solution because if it's working for you, there's nothing actually wrong with the code itself and it's more how I'm running it.  Thanks :)

Comment: @John I think the problem is `load` is removed from the class, and you are trying to access it. Maybe it's replaced by `original`. This also works: `color = capture[i].original[j]`.